# Rearrange elements of array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a vector of points. For example

```
{(1, 5), (3, 2), (1, 8)}
```

Does C++ provide a standard method, so that I can rearrange the elements of the array so that I can select a `(x0, y0)` and rearrange the vector so that `(x0, y0)` is in the middle of the array, the first half of the array contains elements `(xi, yi)` with `xi < x0`or `xi==x0` and `yi < y0` and the second half of the array contains the rest elements.

I am trying to implement this using `std::swap` calls, but I was wondering if there is a standard method to do this sort of thing.

Comment: There's a standard way to ask a question, it involves showing some code.

Comment: `std::partition`

Comment: @kfsone I explained precisely what I am trying to do implement. All I ask is if there is a standard way to do this other than using `std::swap` calls. I don't have a working code that implements the above, but I don't see why that is necessary to answer this simple question

Comment: @LukeLee's suggestion of [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) seems ideal for this.

Comment: Either `partition` or `nth_element`, depending on whether "half" is to be taken literally.

Comment: @LukeLee With `std::partition` how will I get the middle element to be in the  middle and not simply on the first half of the array ?

Comment: @Shiro, for that you should try `nth_element`, as suggested by @T.C

Comment: Are you trying to find the median and partition w/r/t that, or are you trying to partition with respect to an arbitrary point you pick? You can't do both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::partition` to accomplish your task.

Here is an example similar to the one on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) using `std::partition`:

```
struct Point {
    Point(int ix, int iy)
    : x{ix}, y{iy} {} 
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Point> vec { Point(1, 5), Point(3, 2), Point(1, 8), Point(2, 3), 
                        Point(1, 3) };
    const Point middle(2, 0);

    cout << "Original vector:\n";
    for (Point i : vec)
        cout << i.x << "," << i.y << " ";

    auto it = partition(begin(vec), end(vec), [&middle](Point i) {
        return i.x < middle.x && i.y >= middle.y;
    });

    cout << "\nPartitioned vector:\n";
    for (auto beg = begin(vec); beg != it; ++beg) {
        cout << beg->x << "," << beg->y << " ";
    } // First half

    cout << "| ";
    for (; it != end(vec); ++it) {
        cout << it->x << "," << it->y << " ";
    } // Second half
}
```

This gives the output:

```
Original vector:
1,5 3,2 1,8 2,3 1,3 
Partitioned vector:
1,5 1,3 1,8 | 2,3 3,2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the median, and partition according to it, you can use `std::nth_element` with half of vector size as `n`.

If you want to pick a point, and and split the vector into partitions (not necessarily halves, unless you happen to pick the median) that contain lesser on one side, and greater-or-equal on the other, use `std::partition`

> how will I get the middle element to be in the middle and not simply on the first half of the array ?

Swap the target point to front of the vector (if the equals are in the greater side; in the opposite case, swap to end), then use `std::stable_partition` instead of regular partition. Then, the chosen point will end up at the boundary of the partitions.